# IBM Cloud MQ Point-to-point or Pub/sub?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

I'm writing an application that will trigger a task after getting a message from a queue on IBM Cloud MQ. There will be only one producer, and only one consumer (the app i'm writing. Because of this, I thought it was better to use a point-to-point strategy instead of pub/sub. However, while I can use an HTTP REST Get action to get messages from the IBM MQ queue, I would also need to periodically execute a GET to "monitor" the queue.

Wouldn't be better to simply use a pub/sub strategy if that's the case? I don't see the advantage of using point-to-point, although the documentation advices it for my use case.

Comment: You'll still have to get messages from a queue if the message was delivered by pub/sub.

Comment: @MoragHughson right, but with pub/sub I can subcribe to a topic, using point-to-point I have to manually implement polling to continuously check the queue, is this correct?

Comment: @MatiasSalimbene no, you use MQGET with wait, so that you don't have to constantly harass the queue manager.

Comment: You don't say what API/language you are using.   Many implement callback.  JMS/XMS have async listeners which use callback.   This can be used on either point to point or pub sub.   Subscriptions do not magically send you the messages,  the messages still go to a queue (hidden or not hidden) and you need to consume them the same as a point to point queue would be consumed.  Also note the IBM MQ REST API does not support subscriptions.

Comment: My point was that, regardless of whether you subscribe to a topic in order to be sent messages, or just use point-to-point to put messages to the queue, in BOTH instances you have to get messages from the queue. Whether you poll, get-with-wait, use async consume or whatever, doesn't matter, you are still consuming from a queue at the end of the day. So if you have no need for pub/sub, use point-to-point since it doesn't change how to get the messages once they arrive on your queue.

Comment: @JoshMc I'm running MQ con the IBM Cloud, and intended to use it's REST API to Put/Get messages.

Comment: @Roger Right, I think this is what I was missing because I intended to use MQ on Cloud REST API to interact, which would have that functionality. I would need to look an MQ library with MQGET.

Comment: @MoragHughson Yes, I understand I always have to consume messages from a queue. My concern is related to getting those messages. I understand that under pub/sub I got a listener attached to a topic. But I don't get how this is supposed to work under point-to-point. After reading your comments I think it would be with get-with-wait, which means I cannot use REST, and I should be using a library with that functionality.

Comment: As mentioned the IBM MQ REST API does not support sub, only pub. You would need to administratively sub a queue and then use REST to get from that queue.   As you mentioned this wouldn't support a get with wait.  If you develop with a MQ API then callback/async listeners would be my recommendation over get with wait.

Comment: The way you obtain the handle to the queue differs with sub vs P2P, but the way you consume from the handle to the queue once you have it is exactly the same.